# R aggregating data frame

Tags: r, aggregate

If our marriage data frame looks like this

```
   Month  Year marriage_counts
1    Jan  2011              50
2    Jan  2011              30
3    Jan  2011              20
4    Feb  2011              80
5    Feb  2011              10
```

and our Business data looks like this

```
  Month Year
1   Jan 2011
2   Jan 2011
3   Jan 2011
4   Feb 2011
5   Feb 2011
```

this should return a data frame that looks like

```
 Month Year marriage_count
1  Jan 2011            100
2  Feb 2011             90
```

but I'm stuck in here.. can anybody please help me?

Comment: check the `merge()` function

Comment: also `dplyr::group_by()`

Comment: i'm sorry but can you clarify it?

Comment: type `?merge` for help

Comment: Isn't this just `aggregate(marriage_counts ~ Month + Year, marriage, sum)` or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Richard Scriven can you please help this?...

Comment: @james also check `ddply` in the `plyr` package. If you had reproducible data we could show you.

Comment: Why do you have a second data frame?

Comment: be sure to ask a question. "This should return a data frame that looks like". What is "this"?

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```
agg <- aggregate(marriage_counts ~ Month + Year, marriage, sum)
```

Via Dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df_marriage %>% group_by(Month, Year) %>% 
  summarise(marriage_count = sum(marriage_counts))
```

Via Data.table:

```
data.table::setDT(marriage)[, .(marriage_count = sum(marriage_counts)) , by = .(Month, Year)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using `{purrr}`. `slice_rows()` is equivalent to dplyr's `group_by()`.

```r
library(purrr)
df_marriage <- data.frame(Month           = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "May", "May"), 
                          Year            = 2011,
                          marriage_counts = c(50, 30, 20, 80, 10))

df_marriage %>% slice_rows(c("Month", "Year")) %>% by_slice(map, sum)
```